# How to make border for sparkline highcharts table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, sparklines

I have to put the output in a table with complete border, I have tried with border=1, but it's not changing. Can anyone tell me how I can change it?

I am attaching highcharts sparkline code in it. Please check why border is not coming outside of the table. I am unable to the border part in this. I have tried putting border spacing also but again the table is coming without external border.

```js
/**
 * Create a constructor for sparklines that takes some sensible defaults and merges in the individual
 * chart options. This function is also available from the jQuery plugin as $(element).highcharts('SparkLine').
 */
Highcharts.SparkLine = function (a, b, c) {
    var hasRenderToArg = typeof a === 'string' || a.nodeName,
        options = arguments[hasRenderToArg ? 1 : 0],
        defaultOptions = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: (options.chart && options.chart.renderTo) || this,
                backgroundColor: null,
                borderWidth: 0,
                type: 'area',
                margin: [2, 0, 2, 0],
                width: 120,
                height: 20,
                style: {
                    overflow: 'visible'
                },

                // small optimalization, saves 1-2 ms each sparkline
                skipClone: true
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                startOnTick: false,
                endOnTick: false,
                tickPositions: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                endOnTick: false,
                startOnTick: false,
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                tickPositions: [0]
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                backgroundColor: null,
                borderWidth: 0,
                shadow: false,
                useHTML: true,
                hideDelay: 0,
                shared: true,
                padding: 0,
                positioner: function (w, h, point) {
                    return { x: point.plotX - w / 2, y: point.plotY - h };
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    animation: false,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    shadow: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 1,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                radius: 2
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    fillOpacity: 0.25
                },
                column: {
                    negativeColor: '#910000',
                    borderColor: 'silver'
                }
            }
        };

    options = Highcharts.merge(defaultOptions, options);

    return hasRenderToArg ?
        new Highcharts.Chart(a, options, c) :
        new Highcharts.Chart(options, b);
};

var start = +new Date(),
    $tds = $('td[data-sparkline]'),
    fullLen = $tds.length,
    n = 0;

// Creating 153 sparkline charts is quite fast in modern browsers, but IE8 and mobile
// can take some seconds, so we split the input into chunks and apply them in timeouts
// in order avoid locking up the browser process and allow interaction.
function doChunk() {
    var time = +new Date(),
        i,
        len = $tds.length,
        $td,
        stringdata,
        arr,
        data,
        chart;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        $td = $($tds[i]);
        stringdata = $td.data('sparkline');
        arr = stringdata.split('; ');
        data = $.map(arr[0].split(', '), parseFloat);
        chart = {};

        if (arr[1]) {
            chart.type = arr[1];
        }
        $td.highcharts('SparkLine', {
            series: [{
                data: data,
                pointStart: 1
            }],
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + $td.parent().find('th').html() + ', Q{point.x}:</span><br/>',
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}.000</b> USD'
            },
            chart: chart
        });

        n += 1;

        // If the process takes too much time, run a timeout to allow interaction with the browser
        if (new Date() - time > 500) {
            $tds.splice(0, i + 1);
            setTimeout(doChunk, 0);
            break;
        }

        // Print a feedback on the performance
        if (n === fullLen) {
            $('#result').html('Generated ' + fullLen + ' sparklines in ' + (new Date() - start) + ' ms');
        }
    }
}
doChunk();
```

```css
#result {
    text-align: right;
    color: gray;
    min-height: 2em;
}
#table-sparkline {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}
td, th {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    height: 20px;
}

thead th {
    border-top: 2px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}
.highcharts-tooltip>span {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
<table id="table-sparkline">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Income</th>
            <th>Income per quarter</th>
            <th>Costs</th>
            <th>Costs per quarter</th>
            <th>Result</th>
            <th>Result per quarter</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody-sparkline">
        <tr>
            <th>Alabama</th>
            <td>254</td>
            <td data-sparkline="71, 78, 39, 66 "/>
            <td>296</td>
            <td data-sparkline="68, 52, 80, 96 "/>
            <td>-42</td>
            <td data-sparkline="3, 26, -41, -30 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Alaska</th>
            <td>246</td>
            <td data-sparkline="87, 44, 74, 41 "/>
            <td>181</td>
            <td data-sparkline="29, 54, 73, 25 "/>
            <td>65</td>
            <td data-sparkline="58, -10, 1, 16 ; column"/>
        </tr>
       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: change `borderWidth: 0` to `borderWidth: 1`

Comment: borderWidth is not there in the code

Comment: in js file, default options

Comment: what Should I suppose to do?

Comment: That one is for the highcharts, but I want it for the table

Comment: Replace your css for td and th with this `td, th {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    height: 20px;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting border styling for the bottom portion only. You need to change your CSS styling for td and th tag to this

```
    td, th {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```js
/**
 * Create a constructor for sparklines that takes some sensible defaults and merges in the individual
 * chart options. This function is also available from the jQuery plugin as $(element).highcharts('SparkLine').
 */
Highcharts.SparkLine = function (a, b, c) {
    var hasRenderToArg = typeof a === 'string' || a.nodeName,
        options = arguments[hasRenderToArg ? 1 : 0],
        defaultOptions = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: (options.chart && options.chart.renderTo) || this,
                backgroundColor: null,
                borderWidth: 0,
                type: 'area',
                margin: [2, 0, 2, 0],
                width: 120,
                height: 20,
                style: {
                    overflow: 'visible'
                },

                // small optimalization, saves 1-2 ms each sparkline
                skipClone: true
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                startOnTick: false,
                endOnTick: false,
                tickPositions: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                endOnTick: false,
                startOnTick: false,
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                tickPositions: [0]
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                backgroundColor: null,
                borderWidth: 0,
                shadow: false,
                useHTML: true,
                hideDelay: 0,
                shared: true,
                padding: 0,
                positioner: function (w, h, point) {
                    return { x: point.plotX - w / 2, y: point.plotY - h };
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    animation: false,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    shadow: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 1,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                radius: 2
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    fillOpacity: 0.25
                },
                column: {
                    negativeColor: '#910000',
                    borderColor: 'silver'
                }
            }
        };

    options = Highcharts.merge(defaultOptions, options);

    return hasRenderToArg ?
        new Highcharts.Chart(a, options, c) :
        new Highcharts.Chart(options, b);
};

var start = +new Date(),
    $tds = $('td[data-sparkline]'),
    fullLen = $tds.length,
    n = 0;

// Creating 153 sparkline charts is quite fast in modern browsers, but IE8 and mobile
// can take some seconds, so we split the input into chunks and apply them in timeouts
// in order to avoid locking up the browser process and allow interaction.
function doChunk() {
    var time = +new Date(),
        i,
        len = $tds.length,
        $td,
        stringdata,
        arr,
        data,
        chart;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        $td = $($tds[i]);
        stringdata = $td.data('sparkline');
        arr = stringdata.split('; ');
        data = $.map(arr[0].split(', '), parseFloat);
        chart = {};

        if (arr[1]) {
            chart.type = arr[1];
        }
        $td.highcharts('SparkLine', {
            series: [{
                data: data,
                pointStart: 1
            }],
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + $td.parent().find('th').html() + ', Q{point.x}:</span><br/>',
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}.000</b> USD'
            },
            chart: chart
        });

        n += 1;

        // If the process takes too much time, run a timeout to allow interaction with the browser
        if (new Date() - time > 500) {
            $tds.splice(0, i + 1);
            setTimeout(doChunk, 0);
            break;
        }

        // Print a feedback on the performance
        if (n === fullLen) {
            $('#result').html('Generated ' + fullLen + ' sparklines in ' + (new Date() - start) + ' ms');
        }
    }
}
doChunk();
```

```css
#result {
    text-align: right;
    color: gray;
    min-height: 2em;
}
#table-sparkline {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}
td, th {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    height: 20px;
}

thead th {
    border-top: 2px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}
.highcharts-tooltip>span {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
<table id="table-sparkline">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Income</th>
            <th>Income per quarter</th>
            <th>Costs</th>
            <th>Costs per quarter</th>
            <th>Result</th>
            <th>Result per quarter</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody-sparkline">
        <tr>
            <th>Alabama</th>
            <td>254</td>
            <td data-sparkline="71, 78, 39, 66 "/>
            <td>296</td>
            <td data-sparkline="68, 52, 80, 96 "/>
            <td>-42</td>
            <td data-sparkline="3, 26, -41, -30 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Alaska</th>
            <td>246</td>
            <td data-sparkline="87, 44, 74, 41 "/>
            <td>181</td>
            <td data-sparkline="29, 54, 73, 25 "/>
            <td>65</td>
            <td data-sparkline="58, -10, 1, 16 ; column"/>
        </tr>
       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: when you hover over the sparkline it shows the country name but if i want to see the months over there like jan, Q1 Feb Q2 Mar Q3, Apr Q4, then where I have to make changes?

Comment: You are setting the tooltip header content by taking the value in the first column of the row where the graph is present. I think you want to show the months corresponding to the graph points, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I want to show the months instead of countries

Comment: You can declare an array with the corresponding months, and you need to change your tooltip format. add a new question for this.